# Can I use MCP23008 with G6K-2F-Y relay?

Tags: circuit-design

From specs of MCP23008:

- Maximum output current sunk by any output pin is 25 mA.
- Output High-Voltage is VDD-0.7, which is 4.3 V in my case.

From specs of G6K-2F-Y:

- Rated current (mA) is 21.1 mA
- Must operate voltage (V) 80% of max, which is 4 V.
- Coil resistance (Ω) is 237 Ohm (measured actual is 245 Ohm).

I am planning to use 1 relay connected from GPIO to GND.

[image: schematic]

So my calculations gave me 18.1 mA using +4.3 V as described per datasheet which is more than 25% max current from the specs.

Is it safe to use that design? 
If it is not is there anything else with 5V power supply and I2C interface?

---

Updated schematic:

[image: schematic]

I am planning to use internal pull-up resistor to keep p-channel mosfet closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microchip's data sheet:
[image: DC specs MCP23008]

The I/O pin is not spec'd for more than 3mA as a current source. It is anyone's guess how much voltage is dropped below the supply for larger currents, like 20mA.... At 3mA, you're guaranteed 4.3V. It is a very weak switch for coil current.

More promising is sink current - it is a better switch pulling down compared to pulling up. Again, it is anyone's guess how it performs above 8.5 mA. So using just one I/O is *still* risky.

It might be safer to parallel two or three I/O pins, to ensure a strong-enough switch. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIHwfL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just be sure that those three I/O are always switched together high to de-activate the relay, low to activate the relay. Always with the same I2C command....you never want Out_1 fighting Out_2 or Out_3 with one pulling up while the others pull down.

Comment: Thank you, Glen! I think I don't have that many outputs. I added additional schematic with p-channel mosfet. Would this be a better option?

Comment: That IRF7324 is a bit overkill, but OK. You might consider a N-channel switch: cheaper, wider selection. One modification....since MCP23008 powers-up with I/O pins high-impedance, you might want to add a gate-to-source resistor to ensure that your relays are OFF initially.

Comment: N-channel would require extra line on PCB plus I don't have them but I have IRF7324 :-) Plus I can connect several relays in parallel if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used an N-channel MOSFET switching it to ground (low-side switching).  Most MOSFETs have the inductive kickback diode built in. But not all; read the datasheet for the MOSFET of your choice.

Adding more relays in parallel increases the current draw, so the picture of using three outputs to service one relay will not generalize.  I consider sharing output load like this to be risky; the integrated-over-time overload on the first pin can add up.  It may be overloaded for less than a microsecond, but over time this will likely destroy the first output gate turned on.

Not sure why the 100Ω resistor is present.  Gate input current is usually in microamps.  And you have to be careful about Vth, the threshold gate voltage, since you are running not 0 to 5V but are running 0.7 to 4.3 volts.  I typically use a 10KΩ resistor on the gate of my NMOS transistor to keep it turned off.

Comment: I was planning to use  IRF7314TRPBF like this https://www.zoonman.com/files/public/projects/ssb85/ssb85-psu-schematics.png